# Animating the movement of a <div> to another <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to learn jQuery and am tinkering around with a little project to try to learn through practice, but I'm stuck on how to animate the movement of one div to another div.

To clarify, when I click on one div, I would like a different div to move to the div that I clicked on. I'm using appendTo() to move him there, but as you already know, the movement is instant, and I would like to animate the movement.

Here is a fiddle of what is happening currently: https://jsfiddle.net/Chirpizard/jyatn89r/

Just click on a blue dot to see what's happening.

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".node").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('unlocked')) {
      $("#main-char").appendTo(this).animate( {
        top: "+=50"
      }, 1000, function() {
      });
      $(".node").removeClass("activeNode"); //Removes all instances of activeNode
      $(this).addClass('activeNode') //Adds activeNode class to the node clicked on
    }
    else {
      console.log("Sorry, broken");
    }
  });
});
```

I've checked several other posts and haven't found the exact solution I'm looking for. Any guidance on how to get to red dot to slowly move to the clicked element would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got your point ... I don't think you need to appendTo .. just use animate

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".node").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('unlocked')) {
      $("#main-char").animate( {
        top: $(this).offset().top -27
      }, 1000, function() {
      });

      $(".node").removeClass("activeNode"); //Removes all instances of activeNode
      $(this).addClass('activeNode') //Adds activeNode class to the node clicked on
    }
    else {
      console.log("Sorry, broken");
    }
  });

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/jyatn89r/1/)

Comment: Oh, wow. I had no idea that was even possible. Thank you so much! That's far more simple than I thought.

Comment: @user3344629 good luck.. I used -27 in code to make circle center in another circles  if you change another circles height  you should change this number

Comment: @user3344629 if that's the correct answer, then check it!

Comment: Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the `appendTo()` and calculate the distance instead?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".node").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('unlocked')) {
      $("#main-char").animate( {
        top: $(this).offset().top -25
      }, 1000, function() {
      });

      $(".node").removeClass("activeNode"); //Removes all instances of activeNode
      $(this).addClass('activeNode') //Adds activeNode class to the node clicked on
    }
    else {
      console.log("Sorry, broken");
    }
  });

});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/epjxqv/)

Comment: You came up with nearly the exact same solution as the first reply. Thanks for this! I thought I had to use append or prepend to move the actual element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".node").click(function() {
    var nodePosition = $(this).position();
    $("#main-char").animate( {
        top: nodePosition.top + 30
      }, 1000);
  });

});
```

```css
#world-map {
  background: #222;
  min-height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#main-char {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.node {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.node1 {
  top: 100px;
}

.node2 {
  top: 400px;
}

.node3 {
  top: 700px;
}

.node4 {
  top: 1000px;
}

.node5 {
  top: 1300px;
}

.activeNode {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="world-map">
      <div id="main-char"></div>
      <div class="node node1 unlocked"></div>
      <div class="node node2 unlocked"></div>
      <div class="node node3 unlocked"></div>
      <div class="node node4 unlocked"></div>
      <div class="node node5 unlocked"></div>

</div>
```